# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, ocr, tesseract, tess-two, android-studio-import

I cloned the repo from Git Hub, and did all the stepts mentioned without any errors.

Next i started a new project and added libraries under my app as mentioned in https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle.

When i add **build.gradle** to tess-two directory i get an error after the sync is completed

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

I tried a lot to resolve but wasn't able to fix it. 
Need your help guys to figure out the error.

**build.gradle file under tess-two**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

**Event Log**

```
8:59:46 AM Gradle sync started
9:00:12 AM Gradle sync failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
9:00:33 AM Gradle sync started
9:00:35 AM Gradle sync failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
9:00:56 AM Gradle sync started
9:00:58 AM Gradle sync failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

**Log file**
 http://pastebin.com/WVxxmm1c

**settings.gradle of  app**

```
include ':app'
include 'app:libraries'
include 'app:libraries:tess-two'
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle files, and which version of gradle you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
include ':app'
include 'app:libraries' //REMOVE THIS LINE!
include 'app:libraries:tess-two'
```

Since you are defining     `include 'app:libraries'`, Gradle is expecting a `build.gradle` file inside the **app/libraries** folder.

**Configuration with name 'default** happens because gradle doesn't find this file, or if inside the `build.gradle` file Gradle doesn't find the default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it fixed.

I removed include **'app:libraries'** from **settings.gradle of app**.

And added the **tess-two under libraries folder as a module to app**.

I was adding a wrong module, all this time.

But i still cant figure out what the **"Configuration with name 'default'** means.